# Set SelectedValue in ListView CheckBox in Android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I am using `ListView` in `CheckBox` in Android. It is working fine.
Now, I want to set Selected Value in `CheckBox` based on Parameter. So on the loading of the list, if Parameter User is Yes then check that `Checkbox` else does not check. Here, in below code based on country.getUser(), I want to check `CheckBox`. Source : [ListView CheckBox in Android](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

**My Code :**

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<country> {

  private ArrayList<country> countryList;

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
    ArrayList<country> countryList) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
   this.countryList = new ArrayList<country>();
   this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
  }

  private class ViewHolder {
   TextView code;
   CheckBox name;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

   if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
   holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
      Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
       " is " + cb.isChecked(),
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
     }
    });
   }
   else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   Country country = countryList.get(position);
   holder.code.setText(" (" +  country.getCode() + ")");
   holder.name.setText(country.getName());
   holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
   holder.name.setTag(country);

   return convertView;

  }
 }
```

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setChecked` to check the checkbox depends on the value like this

```
if(country.getUser().equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but then it is not storing selected values.

Comment: Have u check source ?

Comment: Oh. use the checkBox view holder.checkBox.setTag(true)