# Listview with section headers and checkboxes

Tags: android, listview

I have created listview with section headers and checkboxes. It's working like a charm except one issue. If my list is less than the screen size then no problem. If my list is longer than screen size say 20 items or more, when i select an item it is selecting the item and when I scroll it is also selecting some other random item. I have searched so much and not able to find the solution. Below is my adopter. I really appreciate help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SectionHeader extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private static int mSelectedItem = -1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();


    static Boolean checkboxstate1[];
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    Boolean selected;
    public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        mSelectedItem = position;
    }


    public SectionHeader(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        checkboxstate1=new Boolean[mData.size()];

    }


    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {       
        int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (rowType) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main_item, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);  
                holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);


                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_section_header, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_header);
                holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.list_main_item, holder.textView);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkbox, holder.chk);

        //else condition for getTag
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageButton imageButton;
        public TextView textView;
        public CheckBox chk;
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set SelectedValue in ListView CheckBox in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172676/set-selectedvalue-in-listview-checkbox-in-android) or this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570035/android-listview-checkboxes-not-staying-checked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that your adapter reuse `CheckBox` object without properly setting the checked state in the `getView(...)` method.
You can do this by storing the checked state of each list entry in `checkboxstate1` array and then call `checkBox.setChecked(checkboxstate1[position])` inside the `getView(...)`.

```
public class SectionHeader extends BaseAdapter {
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

        private static int mSelectedItem = -1;

        private List<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
        private List<Boolean> mCheckedState = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        private Set<Integer> sectionHeader = new HashSet<Integer>();

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ViewHolder holder;

        Boolean selected; // what is this for?

        public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
            mSelectedItem = position;
            mCheckedState.set(position, true);
        }

        public SectionHeader(Context context) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            mCheckedState.add(false);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            mCheckedState.add(false);
            sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {       
            int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (rowType) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main_item, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);  
                        holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_section_header, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_header);
                        holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            holder.chk.setChecked(mCheckedState.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            public ImageButton imageButton;
            public TextView textView;
            public CheckBox chk;
        }
    }
```

Comment: pradithya aria - could you please provide complete code. I tried above option and it's not working for me.

Comment: Updated with sample code. I didn't test it, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: pradithya aria - Thank you so much for the updated code. It is crashing at this line and I am not sure why. holder.chk.setChecked(mCheckedState.get(position));

Comment: pradithya aria - Never mind, I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate from bottom of my heart. I spent numerous hours trying to find out this on my own. Once again thanks a lot.